# Issue in DB2 or Java - Handling CLOB data type

Tags: java, db2

I need to pull comma-separated values from DB2 exactly as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188542/db2-comma-separated-output) question, so after quick googling I found the solution by using following functions in my select clause:

```
SUBSTR(XMLCAST(XMLGROUP(', ' || col_1 AS C ORDER BY col_1)  AS clob), 3) AS RES_COL
```

Now, the output returned is CLOB and not VARCHAR. I tried by increasing VARCHAR limit, but it was giving CAST error. Now, I am getting following exception while reading this CLOB column in JAVA.

```
SQL state [HY000]; error code [0]; [BEA][DB2 JDBC Driver]SQLDIAGGRP was specified and not null.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: [BEA][DB2 JDBC Driver]SQLDIAGGRP was specified and not null.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:83)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:407)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:458)
```

I am not able to find any help regarding what this exception means exactly? What I understand is it is related to JDBC Driver, but can someone explain more on this?

Otherwise, Can DB2 experts tell me how to return VARCHAR instead of CLOB, so that JAVA does not complain when queried?

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am using DB2 9.1, so LISTAGG function is not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by using CAST and TRIM DB2 functions over XMLCAST output. Now I am able to return VARCHAR from the query and JAVA code is working fine too.

```
   SUBSTR(TRIM(CAST(XMLCAST(XMLGROUP(', ' || col_1 AS C ORDER BY col_1) AS clob) AS VARCHAR(4096))), 3) AS RES_COL
```