# Fetch multiple rows with LIKE operator?

Tags: sql, db2

Dealing with a unnormalized database, I have to fetch rows from two tables with a LIKE operator.

```
TblRequests                             TblDetails
ReqID      ReqName                      DetailID    ReqID         DetailDesc
  1        Ledgers                         1          1           Accounting
  2        Inventory                       2          1           Finance
                                           3          1           Finance Audit
                                           4          2           Misc
```

I have to fetch all rows from TblDetails whom have DetailDesc like 'finance' with their detail id. Something like

```
ReqID   ReqName         HasMatch        MatchedDetailsID
  1      Ledgers           Yes            2,3
```

**Update**
I tried to use an inner join but that would return me multiple rows in result.

Answer (score 1):

DB2 (and most relational databases) is not well suited to returning a comma separated list instead of individual rows.

See [DB2 comma separated output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188542/db2-comma-separated-output) for details of transforming the multiple rows into a list.