# SQL statement to summarize, aggregate and concatenate

Tags: sql, db2, concatenation, aggregate-functions

I have a order note table that looks like this:

```
ORDER  NOTE
10000  some notes
10000  another note
20000  a new note
30000  note 1
30000  note 2
```

I want to aggregate with one line per order followed by all related notes, like this:

```
ORDER  NOTES
10000  some notes, another note
20000  a new note
30000  note 1, note 2
```

Is there an SQL statement that can help me?

revision ---

database is IBM db/2, but would prefer SQL ANSI solution if it exists.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188542/db2-comma-separated-output) talks about the same issue using db2.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MS Sql2005+ then this should work for you:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetOrderNotes(@OrderNumber INT) 
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX) 
AS
BEGIN 

    DECLARE @ReturnText NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @ReturnText = ''


    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE OrderNumber = @OrderNumber) 
    BEGIN 
        SELECT 
            @ReturnText = COALESCE(@ReturnText,'') + ISNULL(Note,'') + ', '
        FROM 
            Orders
        WHERE 
            OrderNumber = @OrderNumber

    END 


    RETURN @ReturnText

END


GO 


/*THEN JUST CALL THIS FUNCTION FROM WITHIN YOUR QUERY*/

SELECT 
    OrderNumber 
    , dbo.GetOrderNotes(OrderNumber) AS [Notes Combined] 
FROM 
    Orders
GROUP BY 
    OrderNumber 
ORDER BY 
    OrderNumber
```

Obviously replace the table and column definitions as required but this should get you to where you need to.

I generally try and create functions for this sort of thing so that I don't have to keep writing out the same code/ can use it in multiple places. So if my requirements change then I can change it here and not have to change it in say half a dozen places.

Comment: Except the OP is apparently using DB2, and I'm not sure this technique works.  Besides the fact that it should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse the database tech wasn't in the OP when I answered.