# mysql query and while loop creating a special string

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working on a project where I need to achieve a special task like this.

I have a sql query which fetches all the ids of users who commented on a post and then I use mysql_fetch_array and while loop to create a string of comma separated ids of those users like this.

If the ids of the users on any post are 1 and 4 and 5 and 18 and 88, the string I get is like 1,4,5,18,88.

But the problem is that if any person has made more than one comment then his/her id is added again I do not want this.

Like the users are:

**`1,4,5,4,1,15`**

It gets:

**`1,4,5,4,1,15`**

But I want:

**`1,4,5,15`**

I don't want duplicates.

What I tried:

```
select id from table where comment !=''
mysql_fetch_array()
while (){
   // now joining the ids of commenters here but not duplicate ids
}
```

Comment: Try `select DISTINCT id from table where comment !='' ORDER BY id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use group_concat and you don't even need a loop. A single query will do it.

```
select group_concat(distinct id) from table where comment !=''
```

Comment: and how to print them

Comment: this may solve my problem but i dont know how to print the the values

Comment: it says call to undefined function :(

Comment: echo mysql_result($result, 0);

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM tablename WHERE  comment !='' ORDER BY id
```

It will give you the distinct id from your table

Comment: This is one of the rare occasions where `DISTINCT` is actually the correct answer. Also, if the next question is "how do I make a comma-separated list": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188542/db2-comma-separated-output