# How to convert column values into separated with comma string in DB2

Tags: db2

I am unable to find DB2 query to make column values into one single value separating with comma.

**Actual Table:**

Table Name: Emp

Id  Name 
1   Test1
2   Test2
3   Test3

**Expected Result:**

Name
Test1,Test2,Test3

Cany some one suggest me the way to do it in DB2 or generic way in all databases ?

DB2 Version : 8.1 in windows environment

Many Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [DB2 comma separated output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188542/db2-comma-separated-output)

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what version of DB2 you are using. If you are on DB2 Linux/Unix/Windows, and are at version 9.7 or higher, then you can use the [`LISTAGG` function](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0058709.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-3-1-7):

SELECT LISTAGG(NAME, ',')
FROM EMP