# sql query db2 9.7

Tags: sql, db2, db2-9.7

Recursive query in `DB2` to get items in the chain. There is a table

```
WITH t (id,a) AS (VALUES (1,3),(1,6),(1,9),(2,7),(2,11),(3,5))
SELECT * FROM t
```

The output should be like this

```
id   | a
------------
1    | 3,6,9

2    | 7,11

3    | 5
```

How can I do this using recursive query? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks LIST_AGG or similar.

Comment: as @jarlh suggests above you need to create a string based on each ID using the LIST_AGG function, a resource on this can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25994896/how-to-convert-column-values-into-separated-with-comma-string-in-db2

Comment: Thanks, Jimmy!
I have done this function before but my tutor says do it in another way using recursive query. I am confused. Is there another variant without using lisagg function?