# Looking to Sum up one col, combine results (comma separated) another col and group remaining by a quote number

Tags: sql, db2

I have a result like this 
[Current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmMv1.jpg)
I understand the Group by and using Sum to get price to sum up but How can I get the part numbers to all group together in the result by comma separation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DB2 comma separated output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188542/db2-comma-separated-output)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add listagg function to get the values comma seperated for that group by values.

```
Select  Quote_number
             ,Customer
        ,Customer_no
        ,Address
        ,Other_infor
      ,Sum(Price), LISTAGG(Part_number, ', ')
From table
Group By Quote_number
             ,Customer
        ,Customer_no
        ,Address
        ,Other_infor
```

Answer (score 0):

In brief, you will need to Group By everything that you are not aggregating.

```
Select [Quote number]
      ,[Part number]
      ,[Customer]
      ,[Customer no]
      ,[Address]
      ,[Other infor]
      ,Sum([Price])
From table
Group By [Quote number]
        ,[Part number]
        ,[Customer]
        ,[Customer no]
        ,[Address]
        ,[Other infor]
```

Comment: Thanks Degan, But I am looking to have a result rolled up to a single line item per Quote number and all the parts in one col cell seperated by commas.

Comment: I think I may have figured it out with LISTAGG