# How can I concatenate character values in a GROUP BY query in DB2?

Tags: sql, function, db2, db2-luw

Does someone knows how to get that result bellow ?

There is a sceneario

```
ID          DATE        Description
00041454707 27/07/17    Hospital Sugisawa Pronto Atendimento
00041454707 27/07/17    Hospital Pequeno Príncipe
00041454707 28/07/17    Hospital Sugisawa Pronto Atendimento
```

Result expected :

```
ID          DATE        Description
00041454707 27/07/17    Hospital Sugisawa Pronto Atendimento | Hospital Pequeno Príncipe
00041454707 28/07/17    Hospital Sugisawa Pronto Atendimento
```

Look at result ,I've grouped the first and second one , which has same date 
 **27/07/17** , and concatened in Description field .

I dunno have much background in DB2 .

DB2 V11.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DB2 comma separated output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188542/db2-comma-separated-output)

Comment: I was expecting a function or something like this

Comment: LISTAGG is the function - if you check the linked SO question.

Comment: Yeah , LISTAGG i can get close to result above , BUT , one thing that you forgot is i've grouped 2 rows in one !

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id, dateval,
  LISTAGG(descval, ' | ') AS descvals
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY id, dateval
```

As already mentioned by others here, the trick is done by LISTAGG function.
GROUP BY operator collects the rows into a group, and LISTAGG collects the values into a string with the separator specified.

Comment: A little explanation really improve your answer.