# dynamic pivot in db2

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw, string-aggregation, listagg

So we have PIVOT keyword in Oracle /SQL Serverwhen you convert rows to columns.
Not in DB2, I want to convert row results and concatenate them into a column, dynamically, as in, I do not know the number of rows I might get, they might vary.
Eg
table x

```
COL1  COL2
ABC  10
ABC  20
ABC  30
```

I want to display this as

```
COL1  COL2
ABC   10,20,30
```

But the count of records might vary so I cannot use case.

Want to do this for queries of many tables not a particular query; a function or most preferably in the select query itself.

Comment: Which DB2 "brand" exactly? LUW? iSeries? Z/OS? DB2 LUW supports listagg(): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188542/

Comment: Hi, Yes db2 LUW. Yes, I did use LISTAGG() and it works, however after concatenation, after a certain limit it gives me size error. Any workaround for this? using CAST is an option eg: LISTAGG(CAST(<columname> AS VARGRAPHIC(10000)), ', ')  but still it reserves a fixed length.

Comment: LISTAGG is limited to the max VARCHAR length, i.e. 32000 bytes or so

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I see, is there anyway this can be dynamic, because I will be reserving 32000 necessarily,  and what if the string increases 32000? Any idea for a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Db2 LUW 11.1.4.4 release, you might be able to workaround using [`sysibm.json_array` function](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0070411.html):

```
VALUES JSON_ARRAY(SELECT DEPTNO FROM DEPT);

1
-------------------------------
["F22","G22","H22","I22","J22"]
```

you can then stored the json_array in a character based column, `varchar`, `clob`.

Answer (score 0):

For longer strings.

```
select substr(xmlserialize(
xmlquery('$L/text()' passing XMLAGG(xmlelement(name "a", ','||colname)) as "L")
as clob(1m)
), 2)
from syscat.columns;
```