# How to select two row values in a row in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, concatenation

I want to select two row values in a row and concatenated.

```
id     value
------------
1      abc
1      def
2      ghi
3      jkl
3      mno
3      prs
```

Result should look like:

```
id     value
------------
1      abc, def
2      ghi
3      jkl, mno, prs
```

How can i do that?

Comment: This may seem flippant, but generally the answer is actually `don't`. If you want to do it for display reasons, do that processing in your application. If you want to do it for data reasons, keep the data as a normalised 1:many relationship and consider ways of processing it in that format (We can help with that if you post the use-case you're dealing with). But squashing multiple values into a single value is generally a SQL Anti-Pattern that causes more future pain than it is worth.

Comment: @Dems You are right. The reason is ad-hoc request of Chef .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a delimitted string from a query in DB2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728010/create-a-delimitted-string-from-a-query-in-db2)

Comment: I still recommend trying to avoid doing this.  Needing to is often a symptom of a more pervasive problem.  But the link in my previous comment might start you in the right direction to do it anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link @Dems posted is functionally identical to your requirements.

However, in case you don't have access to the xml functions, here's a recursive CTE version:

```
WITH Indexed(id, value, index) 
            as (SELECT id, value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY value)
                FROM ValueTable),
     Concatenated(id, index, concatenated) 
                 as (SELECT id, index, value
                     FROM Indexed
                     WHERE index = 1
                     UNION ALL
                     SELECT a.id, a.index + 1, a.concatenated || ', ' || b.value
                     FROM Concatenated as a
                     JOIN Indexed as b
                     ON b.id = a.id
                     AND b.index = a.index + 1)
SELECT a.id, a.value
FROM Concatenated as a
EXCEPTION JOIN Indexed as b
ON b.id = a.id
AND b.index > a.index
```

If you have a unique index on the initial table, the `Indexed` CTE can be replaced with a reference to your original table.