# String concatenation in DB2 Stored Procedures

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, db2-luw

I have a DB2 stored procedures to get n number of sequence values and then combine them into a single comma delimited string and return it. The concat function in the stored procedure is not working as expected.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE REFWTX.GET_SEQ_VALUES (in numb integer, OUT SEQVALUES VARCHAR(10000))
LANGUAGE SQL
SPECIFIC GET_SEQ_VALUES
BEGIN
DECLARE SEQ_VAL Integer;
DECLARE CUR_COUNT INTEGER;
SET CUR_COUNT=1;
WHILE (CUR_COUNT <= numb) DO
SELECT NEXTVAL FOR REFWTX.ACK_999_INTR_CTRL_NO_SEQ INTO SEQ_VAL FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
set SEQVALUES = SEQVALUES|| ',' || CHAR(SEQ_VAL);
SET CUR_COUNT=CUR_COUNT+1;
END WHILE;
return;
END
```

The portion of the procedure:
    set SEQVALUES = SEQVALUES|| ',' || CHAR(SEQ_VAL);

is not working as expected. How do I concatenate strings in stored procedures?

Comment: I hope you're not planning on doing anything more than _display_ this information, as comma-separated lists are **extremely** difficult to work with in SQL (especially DB2).  Actually, I believe LUW has some utilities for dealing with aggregating this kind of info, so you don't have to use a cursor (should be faster) - [this site has several examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728010/create-a-delimitted-string-from-a-query-in-db2/17452356#17452356).

Comment: Is SEQVALUES always set to the value that was set at first attempt?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't told us **how** it is "not working as expected". Example inputs and output would be useful.

My guess would be that since you never initialize SEQVALUES, it is set to `NULL` and concatenating anything with `NULL` gives you `NULL`.

Also, instead of

```
SELECT NEXTVAL FOR REFWTX.ACK_999_INTR_CTRL_NO_SEQ INTO SEQ_VAL FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

why not use

```
 VALUES NEXTVAL FOR REFWTX.ACK_999_INTR_CTRL_NO_SEQ INTO SEQ_VAL;
```